# How can I make some objects to move between waypoints?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I managed to make it move between all the waypoints and added also a loop flag.

but what if I have more then one objectsToTeleport ? Now I have only one but if I have for example 10 ? and I want to make that the first start moving between the waypoints after 3 seconds when the first is moving to the next teleporter send the next objectsToTeleport to the first teleporter and so on.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToTeleport = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool loop = false;

    private int objectstoteleportindex = 0;
    private int teleportersindex = 0;
    private bool startnewcoroutine = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move(3));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(teleportersindex != teleporters.Count && startnewcoroutine == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move(3));

            startnewcoroutine = false;
        }
        
        if(teleportersindex == teleporters.Count && loop == true)
        {
            teleportersindex = 0;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move(int SecondsToWait)
    {
        objectsToTeleport[objectstoteleportindex].transform.position = teleporters[teleportersindex].transform.position;

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(SecondsToWait);

        teleportersindex++;
        startnewcoroutine = true;
    }
}
```

And this is the script version with random teleporter select now there are two objects to teleport and each object each time is moving to a random teleporter :

But still I don't understand how to make the objects to teleport to move in the same order between the teleporters(waypoints) but with delay between them. The first object go to teleporter 1 after 3 seconds the first object go to teleporter 2 and the second object go to teleporter 1 and so on each 3 seconds they move to the next teleporter with delay of 3 seconds between them.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Scripting.APIUpdating;

public class Teleporting : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToTeleport = new List<GameObject>();
    public List<GameObject> teleporters = new List<GameObject>();
    public bool loop = false;

    private int objectstoteleportindex = 0;
    private int teleportersindex = 0;
    private bool startnewcoroutine = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(Move(3));
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(teleportersindex != teleporters.Count && startnewcoroutine == true)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move(3));

            startnewcoroutine = false;
        }
        
        if(teleportersindex == teleporters.Count && loop == true)
        {
            teleportersindex = 0;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Move(int SecondsToWait)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToTeleport.Count; i++)
        {
            var teleporter = Random.Range(0, teleporters.Count);
            objectsToTeleport[i].transform.position = teleporters[teleporter].transform.position;
        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(SecondsToWait);

        teleportersindex++;
        
        //objectstoteleportindex++;
        
        startnewcoroutine = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically your problem is that you are using the same index for every object, and you need one index for each object, to keep tracking all of them. One way to achieve this is using a struct or a class (**better use classes!**) that stores the object to teleport, and the index (as you're doing right now) but this index will be related only for the current object.

I'll do something like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TeleporterExample: MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> objectsToTeleport; //list of all posible objects to be teleported
    public List<ObjectToTeleport> currentlyTeleportedObjects;   //list of objects that are currently being teleported at least once
    public List<GameObject> teleporters;    //teleports positions

    public int teleportationsCount = 0; //the number of teleportations have been made

    [Serializable]
    public class ObjectToTeleport
    {
        public GameObject teleportableObject;
        public int teleportOrder;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        //at the start and every 3 seconds call "MoveTeleportableObjects" method
        InvokeRepeating("MoveTeleportableObjects", 0, 1f);
    }

    private void MoveTeleportableObjects()
    {
        //Add new object to teleport queue
        if (teleportationsCount < objectsToTeleport.Count) 
            currentlyTeleportedObjects.Add(objectsToTeleport[teleportationsCount]);

        //move objects on the teleport queue
        for (int i = 0; i < currentlyTeleportedObjects.Count; i++)
        {
            //Get one item to teleport
            ObjectToTeleport item = currentlyTeleportedObjects[i];
            //Get correspondent teleporter            
            GameObject destinationTeleporter = teleporters[currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder];
            //set position of the item to correspondent teleporter
            currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportableObject.transform.position = destinationTeleporter.transform.position;
            //update teleporter order so next time goes to the next teleporter
            if (currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder >= teleporters.Count - 1)
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder = 0;
            else
                currentlyTeleportedObjects[i].teleportOrder++;
        }
        teleportationsCount++;
    }
}
```

Note that there are more ways to call a method with 3 seconds of delay, like using coroutines, etc

Comment: There is a problem in the MoveTeleportableObjects method. This line ObjectToTeleport item = objectsToTeleport[i]; make every 3.3 seconds the item.teleportOrder to be 0 so each 3 seconds it will keep the objects to move in the same two starting teleporters. It will never continue to the other teleporters since item.teleportOrder is 0 and then 1.

Comment: @yasminshoshana I've updated the answer. The problem is that you need to know when to add the objects to the "teleportation queue". I've done one approach, every 3 seconds, one new object will be added to the queue. But there is no problem with the teleportOrder, every teleportOrder is increased for the item, so it won't be 0 again.

Comment: I still don't see the List objectsToTeleport in the Inspector. Only if I'm adding the attribute [Serializable] before the struct then I see the both Lists objectsToTeleport and currentlyTeleportedObjects in the Inspector then I add two items to the objectsToTeleport  List and assign two objects but when running the game the first blue object move to the first teleporter after 3 seconds the red is moving to the first teleporter then it's throwing error. Here is a screenshot : Can you tell me what is wrong with the settings I did in the Inspector ? https://imgur.com/a/8HTKPVH

Comment: And the error exception is on line 31 : currentlyTeleportedObjects.Add(objectsToTeleport[teleportationsCount]); so what am I missing here ?

Comment: @yasminshoshana my bad, I missed to change the name of the list objectsToTeleport to currentlyTeleportedObjects in line 31, updated answer. Tell me if now it works ^^ (I don't have any PC in front to check it)

Comment: @yasminshoshana also the fact that you can't see the lists on the inspector is cause it needs (as you correctly mark) the struct as serializable, either way Unity Editor don't know how to serialize it and show it on the inspector.

Comment: Also notice that I change "struct" to *class*, to avoid creating new instances every time